# In Minecraft 1.19 is there something specific to world generation that places mountains near swamps?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've been using chunkbase maps to determine if there's even a possibility of finding a world like one I might want to play in. I think that this is most likely in a large biomes world, but one thing stands out as I click the random button and scroll around...

If there are any large groups of mountains at all, they always seem to form a ring around swamps. To the point that it seems like it can't be coincidence. This sort of dashes my hopes for a large mountain range that rolls right up to the shore of a large ocean...

But the question I want answered is: Are mountains and swamps somehow linked in the world generation code (perhaps inadvertently)? I think the same must be true of non-large-biome worlds, but that it's not as obvious due to scale.

For those curious I have the map highlight "mountains" and the 3 "peaks" biomes.